# Can I study normed linear spaces without studying inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, normed-spaces

Is it possible to study normed linear space without having a background of inner product space.I want to study normed linear spaces,but still I know nothing of inner product spaces in linear algebra.Will it be a problem?Can someone suggest a good text for that?

Comment: Personally I prefer to work from specific to general when learning a new area, so I think understanding inner product spaces is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do this, and in my opinion even the right order to see things.

You can then see the norm induced by an inner product as a special case of a normed space.

You can take a look at Lax' book on functional analysis. This book introduces normed spaces before it brings up Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Is this book ok for beginners.

Comment: will it help me in better understanding of inner product?

Comment: It depends on your level. Do you know basic real analysis?

Comment: I know point set topology of real numbers,cauchy sequences,continuity,uniform continuity,uniform convergence,compactness,differentiability,power series in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Looks good then. You might want to learn some measure theory too because functional analysis uses this ocasionally.